# displaying different columns from both tables with set operators

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables; one as a depositor and another as a borrower. The depositor has columns as customer name and account number, where borrower has columns as customer name and loan number. While using set operators I want to display account number as well as loan number columns from both tables.

Tables are as follows:

**Depositor**

```
Cust_name                                          Acc_num
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
Sayali                                             101
Priyanka                                           102
Akshata                                            103
Omkar                                              104
Sayali                                             101
Priyanka                                           102
Akshata                                            103
Omkar                                              104
```

**Borrower**

```
Cust_name                                          Loan_num
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
Sayali                                             101
Priyanka                                           111
Swapnil                                            112
Ashwini                                            113

select Cust_name,Acc_num from Depositer
intersect
select Cust_name,Loan_num from Borrower
```

Expected result:

```
Cust_name     Acc_num     Loan_num
----------------------------------
Sayali        101         101
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: `set` is something you use within an update command, not in a select one.
`inner join` is what you usually use for "intersecting" two tables

Comment: sample data and expected results are added @GordonLinoff

Comment: Seems like you're after a `JOIN`.

Comment: I have to use set operator intersect @Larnu

Comment: Why do you "have" to?

Comment: `select Cust_name, Acc_num, Acc_num as Loan_num from Depositer intersect select Cust_name, Loan_num, Loan_num from Borrower;`?

Comment: @Sayali is your expected result correct for the data your shared on your question for depositor and borrower. Update your expected result so that it be consistent with your source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are using the `intersect` operator, both the columns must match to show up in the result, so, you can use the same column as another column like below:

```
select Cust_name, Acc_num, Acc_num as Loan_num
from
(
    select Cust_name,Acc_num from Depositor 
    intersect 
    select Cust_name,Loan_num from Borrower
)t
```